# Flutter Container preenchendo a tela cheia com bordas arredondadas

Tags: flutter, layout, material-design

gostaria de saber como faço um layout parecido com as imagens abaixo no flutter.
Eu tentei utilizar um container, mas ele não preencheu a tela, quando utilizei height: double.infity ele sumiu da tela.`
E se eu deixar a altura fixa em outros devices não vai ficar legal.

```
body: SingleChildScrollView(
        child: Stack(
          children: <Widget>[
            SizedBox(height: 80,),
            Container(
              padding: EdgeInsets.all(10),
              height: 800,
              width: double.infinity,
              color: Colors.transparent,
              child: Container(
                  decoration: new BoxDecoration(
                      color: Colors.white,
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                        topLeft: const Radius.circular(40.0),
                        topRight: const Radius.circular(40.0),
                      )),
                  child: Column(
                    children: <Widget>[
                      Text("Hu"),
                    ],
                  )),
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ou você trabalha com altura fixa ou faz um cálculo

```
MediaQuery.of(context).size.height*0.8
```

dessa forma teu container vai ocupar 80% da tela, isso em qualquer dispositivo.

Altere da forma que desejar...

```
body: SingleChildScrollView(
        child: Stack(
          children: <Widget>[
            SizedBox(height: 80,),
            Container(
              padding: EdgeInsets.all(10),
              height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height*0.8,
              width: double.infinity,
              color: Colors.transparent,
              child: Container(
                  decoration: new BoxDecoration(
                      color: Colors.white,
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                        topLeft: const Radius.circular(40.0),
                        topRight: const Radius.circular(40.0),
                      )),
                  child: Column(
                    children: <Widget>[
                      Text("Hu"),
                    ],
                  )),
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
```

**Explicação**

A classe `MediaQuery` vai te dar muitas informações úteis sobre a sua tela atual, proporções, medidas, contexto e por ai vai...
No seu caso é bom utilizar esta classe pois dela você pode pegar o `size` trazendo assim as medidas de sua tela, como o `width` e o `height`, então com isso você consegue realizar cálculos para melhor exibir teu *Widget*

Se quiser saber mais sobre [MediaQuery](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/MediaQuery-class.html).

Comment: interessante, eu venho da web, essa MediaQuery e como se fosse o window.screen no javascript?

Comment: Cara não sei dizer ao certo, não entendo muito de WEB, mas pelo que já vi em algumas pesquisas parece ser o mesmo conceito...

Comment: entendi, vou fazer o teste aqui do exemplo que me passou

Comment: funcionou perfeitamente, obrigado!